# Prove that there is no $(x,n,m)$ such that $f^n(x)=f^{n+km}(x)$ if $f$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Assume that $f : X\mapsto  X$ is injective. And, we write $f\circ f\circ\dots\circ f(x)=f^n(x)$ for $n$ times composition. Prove that there is no $x\in X$ and no $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that the following equality holds:

$f^n(x)=f^{n+m}(x)=f^{n+2m}(x)=\dots$

It is an impenetrable problem for me, even don't know how to start. Of cousre, it's easy to show that if $f : X\mapsto  X$ is injective, then $f^n : X\mapsto X$ is injective for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$; but does it helps at all?

Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT: The original question:

> Assume that $f : X \to X$ is injective.
>
> a. Prove that $f^n : X \to X$ is injective for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$.
> b. Prove that $f$ has no eventual periodic points.

From the book: C. Adams, R. Franzosa, *Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied*.

Also from the book: We say that $x$ is an eventual periodic point if $x$ is not a periodic
point but $f^n(x)$ is a periodic point for some $n\in \mathbb{Z_+}$.

Comment: Utterly false. Take $f=$ the identity. More is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f^n(x)=f^{n+m}(x)$; since $f$ is injective you may 'cancel' to obtain $f^{n-1}(x)=f^{n-1+m}(x)$. Repeating this procedure eventually leads you to $x=f^m(x)$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Take $f\colon x\mapsto x$ (identity function). For *any* $x\in X$, $n,m \in\mathbb{N}$ you have $f^{n}(x) =  x = f^{n+m}(x) = f^{n+km}(x)$ for all $k \geq 0$.

But $f$ is injective.

You may want another condition on $f$, e.g. "$f$ has no fixed point" (*Edit:* and even this is not enough, as pointed out in the comments below).

Comment: Even "no fixed point" is not enough. Consider multiplication by $-1$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: True -- my bad. (updating my answer).

Comment: @Clement C.: $f^n(x)\neq x$. I explained 'eventual periodic point' in the question; the copy-paste of the exercise (from Topology - C. Adams) is added in EDIT of my question. No other conditions are written.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in interpreting the question. You want to show that $f$ has no eventual periodic points, that is, for all $x \in X$, $x$ is not an eventual periodic point. It's thus sufficient to prove that, for all $x$, if $f^n(x)$ is periodic for some $n > 1$, then $x$ itself is periodic. This isn't what you wrote: it's possible for some $f^n(x)$ to be periodic.

Now it's a bit easier to prove the correct statement. Suppose that $f^n(x)$ is periodic for some $n > 1$. Then there is an integer $m > 0$ such that $f^n(x) = f^{n+m}(x) = f^{n+2m}(x) = \dots$. But the map $f$ is injective, so $f^n(x) = f^{n+m}(x) = f^n(f^m(x)) \implies x = f^m(x)$. By induction, you actually find that $x = f^m(x) = f^{2m}(x) = \dots$, and thus $x$ is periodic. Thus, by your definition, $x$ is not eventual periodic.

Comment: NajibIdrissi&user59363 : Thank you very much for your great answers. PS I have to 'accept' the other, since I received it a bit earlier.